# Any ideas on how to get WordPress multithreaded?

Tags: wordpress, multithreading

Any ideas on how to get WordPress multithreaded?
Is it possible to set the thread and multithread in WordPress, because I would like to make some background.
thank you!

Comment: Most PHP versions aren't built to be run in a threaded environment. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I have PDF generation process in one of my project.
functionality is when clicking the checkout button based on the user input.I will generate the PDF,at the time the PDF generation take a long while to generating the PDF.I try to make PDF generation in the background.So user won't wait for the long while.they simple click and go-cart page.In the background, the PDF generation is running on.
this is what I try to achieve.

Comment: You can use the WordPress cron which execute in the backgroud : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/

Comment: My Version PHP version is php 5.6